# how to collect twitter data from multiple IDs

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a list of  14 user IDs and I have to collect them from each of the users.I run this Code to get the IDs from different Account. How could I get data from all the accounts?

```
# assign the values accordingly
consumer_key = 'XXXX'
consumer_key_secret = 'XXXXX'
access_token = 'XXXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXXXX'
  
# authorization of consumer key and consumer secret
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_key_secret)
  
# set access to user's access key and access secret 
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
  
# calling the api 
api = tweepy.API(auth)
  
# the screen name of the user
screen_name = ["m","b","c"]
ID = []

# fetching the user
for i in range(len(screen_name)):
    user = api.get_user(screen_name[i])
    #fetching the ID
    ID.append(user.id_str)
    del(user)
ID
```

i got this
['15454564','25645464','35456464']

HOW CAN I GET THE DATA FROM MULTIPLE IDS

Comment: What data are you trying to collect?

Comment: tweet_contributors tweet_coordinates tweet_created_at tweet_display_text_range tweet_entities tweet_extended_entities tweet_favorite_count tweet_favorited tweet_full_text tweet_geo tweet_id tweet_id_str tweet_in_reply_to_screen_name tweet_in_reply_to_status_id tweet_in_reply_to_status_id_str tweet_in_reply_to_user_id tweet_in_reply_to_user_id_str tweet_is_quote_status tweet_lang tweet_metadata tweet_place tweet_possibly_sensitive tweet_quoted_status tweet_quoted_status_id tweet_quoted_status_id_str tweet_retweet_count user_default_profile_image user_description user_entities user_favourites_ct

Comment: user_follow_request_sent user_followers_count user_following user_friends_count user_geo_enabled user_has_extended_profile user_id user_id_str user_is_translation_enabled user_is_translator user_lang user_listed_count user_location user_name user_notifications user_profile_background_color user_profile_background_image_url user_profile_background_image_url_https user_profile_background_tile user_profile_banner_url user_profile_image_url user_profile_image_url_https user_profile_link_color user_profile_sidebar_border_color

Comment: user_profile_sidebar_fill_color user_profile_text_color user_profile_use_background_image user_protected user_screen_name user_statuses_count user_time_zone user_translator_type user_url user_utc_offset user_verified tweet_source_url

Comment: i want to collect data from several accounts to get all information for example location user_screen_name text etc....

Comment: a i said before

Answer (score 0):

To get data from multiple Tweet IDs, just create separate variables or arrays to store the data you want. And to pull data from Tweet IDs, just check the Tweepy documentation at https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/. Good luck, and let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: hi , sorry i dont understand you answer